# Upload/Download text files in Java?

Tags: java, database, download, upload, text-files

I'm currently trying to code a fairly simple program in Java to keep a database on a small library at my university. I'd like for multiple computers to be able to use this program using a shared database stored in a text file that would be downloaded when the program is run, and uploaded once the user is finished using the program and making any edits to the database. I don't know how to go about this at all and would be very grateful for any pointers on a direction to take.

Comment: If you have more than one user at once, things will go horribly wrong.  You should use a real database.

Comment: Not simultaneously. Only one user would ever access it at once.

Comment: *" I'd like for multiple computers to be able to use this program using a shared database stored in a text file that would be downloaded when the program is run"* ... hmmm, no, you don't, really.  The process of merging the changes would be a lot more work then it's worth.  Instead, you should consider using some kind of database server which you program can connect to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to other computers in Java, you should use [Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html), and define your own Protocol (Basically, your protocol would consist on a handshake, and some way on asking the other part of the connection to send the text's data). Anyways, I'd recommend you using a simple [SQLite](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/) database

To read and save files (txt is a raw text file without any special format), check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)

If you'd like the program to display the text, you should learn a bit about [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Also, try looking a bit in google before asking here